# How to make background color stay consistent on mobile & desktop?

Tags: css

I created this Flashcards React web app for my son, and we kept facing this annoying CSS issue where I kept seeing my background color change from black to white when I scrolled down. This issue only happens on a phone.

`Phone`

[image]

As you can can see that it's working fine on Desktop.

`desktop`

[image]

This is my entire CSS for that page

```
.thumbnails-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

## https://norden-flashcards.netlify.app/

Comment: Change the `height` on the `.categories-page` class to `min-height`

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rule for `.categories-page` (= the element that has the dark background), change `height: 100vh;` to `min-height: 100vh;` to allow it to grow when there is more content.

Answer (score 0):

Set `height: 100%;` instead of `height: 100vh;` in your `.categories-page` class to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By checking your app you should remove the `height:100vh` of your `.categories-page` class

```
 .categories-page {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg,#000,#333 50%);
        background-position: 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh; ---> remove this line
    }
```